# Get user input from form and update it by id - mongodb and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

How to update a record by hard coding the MLAB ID in the server using  app.post.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.post('/form1', function (req, res, next) {
  record.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": ObjectId("THE ID IN MLAB")}, req.body, {new: true}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).end()
    } else {
      res.status(200).end()
    }
  })
});
```

Documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: @stack My bad, I should've explained. I've updated the code. Replace your /form1 handler with this. This **should** work.

Comment: Hey @stack, that's a different problem. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/32368096/2691993 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/34158112/2691993 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/48150072/2691993 .
I suggest you read a little about transferring data from server to client. If you're stuck, you can always create a new question with your specific problems. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your record instead of inserting a new one. To update your record your record must contain an immutable field.

[Refer this question to see how to find and update with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose)